# Lisp / Scheme : Evaluating nested empty list/cons : (())

Tags: scheme, lisp, common-lisp, empty-list, expression-evaluation

I'm using this [Lisp compiler](https://rextester.com/l/common_lisp_online_compiler) for testing

There is one things that I don't get it :
If an empty list `()` evaluate to itself :

```lisp
(format t "~:a" ())
;; => ()
```

why do evaluating several nested empty list `()` don't evaluate to an empty list ?

```lisp
(format t "~:a" (()))
;; => EVAL: undefined function NIL
;; why not () ?

(format t "~:a" ((())))
;; => EVAL: (NIL) is not a function name; try using a symbol instead
;; why not () ?
```

From my point of view, `()` and `NIL` are the same, so the inner empty list should first evaluate to itself, then the outer list should "call" the newly inner evaluated empty list

I my head, I see it like this should happen when doing the calculation:
(bold + italic = what is currently evaluated)

(()) => (***()***) => ***(***()***)*** => ()

Seem like Scheme also don't allow nested empty list call

*Thank for reading*

Comment: In your diagram the last arrow is where things are different from your expectations: `(x)` for some value `x` doesn't return `x` itself, it is a function call

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Common Lisp and its ancestors, the empty list, `()`, is self evaluating by special dispensation: it's the only list which has this property.  It's also the only list which is *also a symbol*, in this case the symbol `nil` (really `NIL`).  It's tempting to think that, somewhere in the guts of the implementation something just said the equivalent of `(defconstant nil ())`, but it's much more magic than that:

```
> (eq () 'nil)
t

> (symbolp ())
t

> (symbol-name ())
"NIL"
```

It's not just the value of the symbol `nil`, it *is* the symbol `nil`.  `()` is really very magic in CL. More magic than it is in Scheme, say: in Scheme it's still magic just rather less so.  In Scheme, `()` is the only list which is not a pair (a cons), but it is not also a symbol and it is not self-evaluating.

So, OK, that explains why `()` evaluates to itself: it does so because it is magic.

So now consider trying to evaluate this form:

```
(())
```

Well, first of all *this is not the empty list*: its a list with one element, which is the empty list.  From the point of view of evaluation it is a [compound form](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_c.htm#compound_form).  Well, as the empty list (the first element of this list) is *also* `nil` we can rewrite this compound form as

```
(nil)
```

This is *the same thing*: `(equal '(nil) '(()))` is true.

OK, well now what does the evaluator do with compound forms?  It looks at their first element and decides what to do (see [here](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_abab.htm).

- If it is a symbol, then the symbol should name one of

  - a special operator
  - or a (possibly local) function
  - or a (possibly local) macro

  and it will be processed accordingly.
- If it is not a symbol it may be a list beginning `(lambda ...)` which is turned into an anonymous function and called.
- There are no more cases.

Well, which is `(())`, or equivalently `(nil)`?  It's a compound form, and the first element of it is the symbol `nil`.  So

- does `nil` name a special operator?  no -- `(special-operator-p 'nil)` is false;
- does `nil` name a macro?  no -- `(macro-function 'nil)` is false;
- does `nil` name a function?  No - `(fboundp 'nil)` is false.

So the evaluator can't process this form: it's not legal.

---

Note that in Scheme the same thing would also be not legal, but for slightly different reasons:  for Scheme, the empty list is not self-evaluating, so the evaluator sees `(())` and says (ignoring macros this time) that this is a procedure call, where the procedure is going to be the result of evaluating `()`, but that's an error.  If I said `(define nil '())` then `(nil)` would still be an error: it would evaluate `nil` and get `()`, but `()` is not a procedure.

---

A surprising thing about CL is that `(())` can be *given* (local) meaning.  This is, amazingly enough, conforming CL:

```
(flet ((() () ()))
  (()))
```

It's conforming because you're allowed to locally establish function definitions for symbols in `CL` if they do not have global function definitions:

> If an external symbol of the `COMMON-LISP` package is not defined as a standardized function, macro, or special operator, it is allowed to lexically bind it as a function (e.g., with `flet`), to declare the `ftype` of that binding, and (in implementations which provide the ability to do so) to trace that binding. -- [CLHS](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/11_ababa.htm)

And then `()` is the symbol `nil` which does not have a global function definition.

Comment: Oh okay I see thank, it because of compound and because the list is not empty, it's containing one element, the empty list.

(Fun fact : I was making a Lisp/Scheme interpreter in C, and they way I implemented it `(())` work but I was wondering about why it don't in lisp/scheme).

Thank for the links too !

Comment: I really like the bit about: "(()) can be given (local) meaning." My first thought was "but you're binding a symbol in CL..." and then you provided the exact reference that says "you can do that, if it doesn't already have a binding (of certain types)".  That attention to detail is great!

Comment: `()` isn't magic; it's just the empty list, one element shorter than `(42)`. What's magic is that the empty list is the symbol `nil`. So when the reader scans `()`, it has to return `nil`. Since `nil` is self-evaluating, `()` has to be also.  If `nil` were not self-evaluating, but had to be quoted, so would `()`. In early Lisp, `T` was not self-evaluating and had to be quoted; then they bound a global variable called `T` which had itself as a value. A similar thing could have been done with `NIL`; and that would not be magic at all, just `()` producing `NIL`, which is then resolved as a var.

Comment: @Kaz It is magic (or I consider it so).  In both Scheme and CL it is a list but not a cons, which is entirely more magic than being (say) just a zero-length vector.  In CL it is additionally magic because `car` & `cdr` work on it even though it is not a cons and finally that it is a list *and a symbol* which is quite seriously magic.  That's how I define 'magic'.